# Making a single decorator of out multiple

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Say, I have something like:

```
@decorator1
@decorator2
def myfunc()
   # ....
```

How do I declare a new decorator `both_decorators` which would invoke `decorator1` and `decorator2` in order, essentially making it an alias for them? So that I could write instead:

```
@both_decorators
def myfunc()
   # ....
```

The idea is to save typing when multiple decorators are used the same way in many cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
def both_decorators(func):
    return decorator1(decorator2(func))
```

because that's all decorators do, really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Something along the lines of:

```
def both_decorators(*decs):
    def decorator(dc):
        for dec in reversed(decs):
            dc = dec(dc)
        return dc
    return decorator
```

Then all you would need to do is add them

```
@both_decorators(decorator1, decorator2)
def myfunc():
    #something happening here.
```

Personally I would prefer this, as you can choose which decorator you would want and which not.

Comment: This creates more typing, not less :)